# How to get the value when multiple type are the same in flutter's provider?

Tags: flutter, dart

If there are two types of the same that need to be shared, how to get their values ​​in the `Provider.of`?

```dart
void main() {
  final int counter1 = 48;
  final int counter2 = 12;

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<int>.value(value: counter1),
        Provider<int>.value(value: counter2),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _counter1 = Provider.of<int>(context);  // ??
    final _counter2 = Provider.of<int>(context);  // ??
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not do this, you have to change the type somehow.

You can create a class which container simple counter value and that how you can change the type of one int.

if you use provider at the same time then when you access provider in child then you can receive the value of the closest provider only.

for more info look at the official [document](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/)